# apache mod_rewrite to force index.php

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

im pulling my hair out.

im utilising mod_rewrite to run through index.php if %{REQUEST_URI} isnt an existing document:

```
#Any request (page) which doesnt exist (item pages, special urls, categories etc)
#get routed through urlparse, where PHP takes over nicely
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) urlparse.php?url=$1 [L]
```

taking this into account, **i want a rule BEFORE this one which stipulates**:

```
if %{REQUEST_URI} is empty then pretend it is index.php
```

my understanding is for a url like

```
http://www.server.com/
```

then %{REQUEST_URI} is "" (an empty string), verses

```
http://www.server.com/something/whatever
```

where %{REQUEST_URI} is "something/whatever".

thanks for any help you guys can give.

Comment: Isn't there a way to tell apache to use index.php as the 404 document? Wouldn't that do this for you without rewrite?

Comment: yes, but for this particular situation that wouldntve helped - one of the categories actually matched an empty string ("http://www.server.com/" was the category "Shoes" cause "Shoes" url was "" (empty string) in the mysql). i wanted to firmly avoid that circumstance by forcing index.php if %{REQUEST_URI} was empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
RewriteRule ^$ index.php
```

Comment: thankyou muchly. i had to add [L] to the rule to force apache to not parse the other rules, but youve relieved my stress-headache.